# Why is clojure adding namespace qualifiers to names inside a backquote?

Tags: macros, clojure, datomic

I am trying to build datalog queries programmatically, but keep running into the problem that I will illustrate with an example function:

```
(defn test-expr [attribute]
  `[?entity ~attribute ?value]])
```

When I run (test-expr 3), I would expect the output:

```
 [?entity 3 ?value]
```

But instead, I get

```
[mynamespace/?entity 3 mynamespace/?value]
```

Which obviously is not what I want. Is there a way to tell clojure "please just quote the list and expand variables I tell you to?"

Comment: As to the reason why, it's to prevent users (*cough* you) from accidentally breaking your macros by defining functions and/or variables with the same name you're using.

Comment: @Cubic, agreed. As far as I understand, this is some kind of compromise between Scheme hygienic macros and Common Lisp plain macro systems: macro definitions look nearly exactly like Common Lisp ones (this is good, since Scheme macros are harder to write IMO), but by default there is certain level of hygiene present - symbols are not captured blindly but are prefixed with namespace instead. And it is always possible to fall back to plain substitutions when needed (e.g. for anaphoric macros).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
(defn test-expr [attribute]
  `[~'?entity ~attribute ~'?value])
```

Here you first unquote the syntax quotation and then immediately quote the symbol (`~'` construct) again. The result is namespace-less symbol.

It is equivalent to the following, which explains how it works:

```
(defn test-expr [attribute]
  `[~(quote ?entity) ~attribute ~(quote ?value)])
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is the backtick library by Brandon Bloom https://github.com/brandonbloom/backtick

It was built for the exact problem you describe. It supplies a command named 'template' that works like the backtick but without the namespacing stuff.

In Clojure, quasiquotation and namespace resolution are mixed together in a single feature. This has great benefits for writing macros in a language like Clojure, which is a "Lisp-1" (as opposed to Common Lisp, which is a "Lisp-2", with separate namespaces for functions and variables.)

I also agree that it might have been better not to conflate these features, but it would have made the writing of macros in Clojure less elegant, so I can see why it works the way it does.